# Condensing code: Check that multiple columns follow a boolean in data frame in R

Tags: r, boolean, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) that has some NA values. I wanted to extract the rows where there are NA values across multiple columns (in the example below, I am doing so for columns 12-20):

```
NArows = which(is.na(df[,20])&is.na(df[,19]&is.na(df[,18])&is.na(df[,17])&is.na(df[,16])&is.na(df[,15])&is.na(df[,14])&is.na(df[,13])&is.na(df[,12])))
```

Is there a more readable (and condensed) way to accomplish this, without putting each column condition surrounded by & sign?

Thank you for any help...

Comment: You should provide an example data set so we won't have to create it on our own.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry. I usually do (at least use a built-in dataframe like mtcars). I will try to find one with NAs in it to use in the future for examples like this. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `mtcars` and insert `NA` in some rows and then show your desired output.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't provide a reproducible example. Everyone is just guessing and fighting each other. Eventually good answers get deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cols <- 12:20
NArows <- which(apply(df[cols],1,function(y)sum(!is.na(y))==0))
```

It slices your df to just the 'cols' you care about,then applies to each row the test is.na() and if it finds all values in those cols are NA it adds that row number to NArows.

Or based on david arenburg's answer, this flags any rows with 2 or more NAs:

```
NArows <- which(rowSums(is.na(df[12:20])) > 1L)
```

Adapting it to more closely match your requirements, this flags only rows where all are NAs:

```
cols <- 12:20
NArows <- which(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == ncol(df[cols]))
```